# Missing HTML output [BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup on Jupyter notebook to parse HTML data from this website (http://www.jepoc.or.jp/hydro/index.php?_w=usData&_x=areashow3). I only require data from the table (header and values).

However, it seems that the parsed soup objects only showed values from the table headers while all the table value items (e.g. numerical values) are missing. Data from `<tr class = "rowOdd">` and `<tr class = "rowEven">` are missing.

Here's the code I've written:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.jepoc.or.jp/hydro/index.php?_w=usData&_x=areashow3")
print(len(r.text))

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5")
soup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing everything to a file or change soup at the end of your code to

```
soup.get_text()
```